# How to define additional methods when implementing __new__

Tags: python, class

In this example, the user has to deal with two file types (.txt and .csv). However, the used does not want to bother checking the file type and consequently instance the dedicated class. Instead, the user crated an instance of FileTypeFactory using `__new__` and the appropriate type will be instanced and returned. However, I don't see how to add new methods to the factory without occurring in `AttributeError`

```
class TXT:
    def is_valid(self):
        return False

class CSV:
    def is_valid(self):
        return True

class FileTypeFactory:
    def __new__(cls):
        for FileType in [TXT, CSV]:
            file_type = FileType()
            if file_type.is_valid():
                return file_type

    def factory_method(self):
        print('Running factory_method')


c = Factory()
c.__class__.__name__
# Returns: 'CSV'
c.factory_method()
# Returns: AttributeError: 'CSV' object has no attribute 'factory_method'
```

Comment: Factories don't exist to add methods to objects. Why don't you just define that method in a base class of `TXT` and `CSV`?

Comment: Because in practice FileTypeFactory.factory_method needs to instance TXT and CSV. An example of this behaviour is `datetime.datetime`

Comment: I don't understand. Maybe you could make `TXT` and `CSV` inherit from `FileTypeFactory`?

Comment: `c` is an instance of `CSV`, not `FileTypeFactory`. If you expect `CSV` to have a `factory_method` attribute, you either need to define it explicitly, inherit from a class that has it, or use a metaclass that defines  it.

Comment: "Instead, the user created an instance of `FileTypeFactory`...". No, he didn't. He used `FileTypeFactory.__new__` to return an instance of an entirely different class unrelated to `FileTypeFactory`.